# Error ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
namespace Elite_Shop
{
        public partial class Bill : Form
        {
            int j;
            int total = 0;
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EliteShop;Integrated Security=True  ");



        public Bill()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void get_value(int i)
        {
            j = i;
        }
        private void Bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
            sqlcon.Open();
            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Salesman_Table Where SMID="+j+"";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds.DataTable1);

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.CommandText = "Select * from Sale_Table Where OrderID=" + j + "";
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(ds.DataTable2);
            da2.Fill(dt2);

            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
            {

                total = total + Convert.ToInt32(dr2["Sub Total"].ToString());
            }
            SaleReport sr = new SaleReport();
            sr.SetDataSource(ds);
            sr.SetParameterValue("Grand Total", total.ToString());
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = sr;
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, the following error message is returned:

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Where are you telling the command what connection to use?  set `cmd.Connection = sqlCon` before executing the query

Comment: Note: concatenating values to create SQL is a very bad idea, even with integers - you should use *parameters*

Comment: yeah you r right

Comment: Also, you should not keep a connection object in a class variable.  You should create the connection at the point at which you need it and then dispose of it imediately.  Ideally, you would do this inside a `using` block.

Comment: A Select command is not a Non Query. You are running cmd twice. Once with ExecuteNonQuery and again with a .Fill.

Comment: You go to the trouble of converting your data row value to an Int32 but then you call .ToString on it and try to add a string to an int.

Comment: Why not use SUM in you sql statement and let the server do the addition?

Comment: Can you modify this code ??

Comment: Above Code is Running fine..There is no Error

Comment: But I need your suggestions how can i improve it better and better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Connection property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection?view=netframework-4.8) on the SqlCommand:

```
cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
```

Comment: yeah i have missed to set connection.